# validating duplicate records in dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to see duplicate records if name is duplicate in column then both record should show as duplicate . but in my code only one is showing as duplicate.

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","KTN2542","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,Ajay","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))


df <- df %>% mutate("Duplicateid" =duplicated(ID,incomparables = c("",NA)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `any` in combination with `group_by(ID)` as follows

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate("Duplicateid" = any(duplicated(ID,incomparables = c("",NA))))

#> # A tibble: 16 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [15]
#>    ID        city  Name           Duplicateid
#>    <chr>     <chr> <chr>          <lgl>      
#>  1 "DEV2962" DEL   dev,akash      FALSE      
#>  2 "KTN2252" mum   singh,Ajay     FALSE      
#>  3 "ANA2719" DEL   abbas,salman   FALSE      
#>  4 "ITI2624" MUM   lal,ram        FALSE      
#>  5 "DEV2698" DEL   singh,nkunj    FALSE      
#>  6 "HRT2921" del   garg,prabal    FALSE      
#>  7 ""        MUM   ali,sanu       FALSE      
#>  8 "KTN2624" DEL   singh,kunal    FALSE      
#>  9 "ANA2548" del   tomar,lakhan   FALSE      
#> 10 "ITI2535" MUM   thakur,praveen FALSE      
#> 11 "DEV2732" mum   ali,sarman     FALSE      
#> 12 "HRT2837" mum   khan,zuber     FALSE      
#> 13 "ERV2951" mum   singh,giriraj  FALSE      
#> 14 "KTN2542" mum   sharma,lokesh  TRUE       
#> 15 "KTN2542" DEL   pawar,pooja    TRUE       
#> 16 "ITI2210" DEL   sharma,nikita  FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We may use `anyDuplicated` as well

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(ID ) %>%
    mutate(DuplicateId = anyDuplicated(ID, incomparables = c("", NA)) > 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 4
# Groups:   ID [15]
   ID        city  Name           DuplicateId
   <chr>     <chr> <chr>          <lgl>      
 1 "DEV2962" DEL   dev,akash      FALSE      
 2 "KTN2252" mum   singh,Ajay     FALSE      
 3 "ANA2719" DEL   abbas,salman   FALSE      
 4 "ITI2624" MUM   lal,ram        FALSE      
 5 "DEV2698" DEL   singh,nkunj    FALSE      
 6 "HRT2921" del   garg,prabal    FALSE      
 7 ""        MUM   ali,sanu       FALSE      
 8 "KTN2624" DEL   singh,kunal    FALSE      
 9 "ANA2548" del   tomar,lakhan   FALSE      
10 "ITI2535" MUM   thakur,praveen FALSE      
11 "DEV2732" mum   ali,sarman     FALSE      
12 "HRT2837" mum   khan,zuber     FALSE      
13 "ERV2951" mum   singh,giriraj  FALSE      
14 "KTN2542" mum   sharma,lokesh  TRUE       
15 "KTN2542" DEL   pawar,pooja    TRUE       
16 "ITI2210" DEL   sharma,nikita  FALSE
```